# Universal clock for humans contained in the telomeric sequences?

Tags: dna, dna-replication

I don't know if this would make sense, but imagine that we could only suffer from natural aging (not diseases whatsoever involved). Is there an estimate of what is our natural maximum lifespan that a human can have?

I learned that the telomeric sequences protect sensible information in DNA, and that somatic cells suffer from a cut of these sequences in each replication. So I wonder if this is a natural clock, and if it has been estimated how much time do we have naturally.

Comment: If the clock is universal, it obviously doesn't run at the same rate for everyone.

Comment: I should have written on average for the human beings.